# making a vertical sliding menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

here's my html:

```
<ul id="dmenu">
    <li><a href="#">menu item one</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">menu item two</a>
            <ul class="displayNone">
                <li><a href="#">menu item one</a>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks on one of the a tags, I want my code to check wether there are any ul tags in the parent li tag. If there are, I then want to preventdefault action for the a tag and slideToggle the child ul element

my jquery atm:

```
$('#dmenu > a').click(function(e) {
    if (this.parent().has('ul')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children().slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: it's not working - the code does nothing and I have no idea why

Comment: Is this wrapped in document.ready?

Comment: yup, nothing is happening

Comment: Change your selector to `#dmenu > li a`. Assuming `#dmenu` is the `ul` element, your original selector won't do anything as `a` is never a *direct* child of `#dmenu`.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing the slide toggle on the child of the `a`

change `$(this).children().slideToggle();` to

```
$(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
```

also your selector `#dmenu > a` is wrong - your top level menu doesn't have that id and if it did there are no direct anchors as children of the ul - remove the `>` and add the id `dmenu` to you top `ul` or container element

**Edit**

As pointed out by Austin, as you have nested lists you may want to limit your click events to the top level only so you can use the `#dmenu > li a`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z4T4Y/)

Comment: It would be better just to use `#dmenu > li a`.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst why add an extra selector, you are slowing down your query

Comment: Because there are nested lists. Using that query would eliminate the need of checking if the parent is an unordered list.

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot about the nested list thing